# Visual Studio 2012 doesn't generate an executable file

Tags: c++

I recently re-downloaded Visual Studio 2012 Pro from DreamSpark for class, and it simply refuses to generate a .exe file while I'm working with C++. I go to debug, and I get a window reading the following:

Unable to start program 'C:\ [file path]\debug\Project3.exe'

System cannot find file specified.

Sure enough, I check through my folder, and there is, in fact, no Project3.exe in the Debug folder; in fact, there is no file called Project3.exe in the entire directory for Project3. The only logical explanation that I can come up with is that it simply isn't generating Project3.exe for some reason.

I have tried several proposed solutions (at least the ones that I could understand) and nothing has helped. I've tried moving the .cpp files and .h files around the folder (because they were also mysteriously absent) but nothing worked. Any ideas on what the problem could be? It's just been installed, completely standard preferences; I haven't changed anything.

Comment: When you build your project, are you getting any errors?

Comment: what happens when you compile the project (default key is f7, if I remember correctly).  Post any and all error message that are shown.

Comment: Look at the "output" window as you run the build. Do you see your program being compiled and linked?

Comment: Please post the entire output of a *Rebuild*. Without that information we can only speculate as to what's going on.

Comment: @thurizas: here is what I get from using the F7 shortcut:

1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.Cpp.Platform.targets(42,5): error MSB8020: The builds tools for Visual Studio 2010 (Platform Toolset = 'v100') cannot be found. To build using the v100 build tools, either click the Project menu or right-click the solution, and then select "Update VC++ Projects...". Install Visual Studio 2010 to build using the Visual Studio 2010 build tools.

I guess I was getting errors; I was just looking in the wrong place, lol.

Comment: @Robert, just a wild guess here, it appears that the solution that you are attempting to build might be a VS2010 solution and not a VS2012 one. Or one of your downloads is corrupted.  Any chance you could make the project3 available?  I'd like to load it up in my version of VS2010 and see what happens.

Comment: @thurizas any ways you could recommend I do that? Like, with some hosting website of some kind?

Comment: yea like a hosting site (if you have one), or PM on the boards -- I'm assuming members can send private message to each other.  However, I have never done it, nor do I know how.

Comment: @Qix : I'm not entirely sure what you mean by a Rebuild (I am a student, and don't quite know everything about VS), but I will do it once I figure out what you're talking about.

Comment: @robert - under build menu, there are three we want to consider (1) clean - this option removes all generated and intermediate files produced as a consequence of building your solution.  (2) build - this will recompile any files that have been modified since the last build, and the relink the solution to produce an executable (or library).  (3) rebuild - this first performs a clean (removing all intermediate files) and then performs a build, because all the intermediate files have been deleted all the files associated with you solution will be compiled and these will be linked

Comment: @Qix : Ok, did a Rebuild, and I got the error I posted above, but I noticed that the first line read: "1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: Project3 (Visual Studio 2010), Configuration: Release Win32 ------" meaning that it thinks this is a visual studio 2010 project. This is strange, because I made it with VS 2012, by making an empty project, and writing the code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Right click the solution file, select menu option 'Configuration Manager...'
Find your project in the list, make sure that the 'Build' checkbox is selected.

If it is, I would also suggest opening up the project file in a text editor.  Confirm that there is a section like the following:

**Edit**  This is an example from a c# project file, but the premise still applies, you should have a property group with the configuration and platform that matches what you are building against.  See the code section further down for a c++ project specific example.

```
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <Prefer32Bit>false</Prefer32Bit>
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

The important thing is that you have a configuration|platform section that matches the the configuration and platform you are building against, and that the outputpath is the folder you expect it to be in.  This will usually be the case for a trivial example such as debug, but if mess around with adding or changing configurations, this can get out of whack.

**Edit:**  Before acknowledging my edit below, you should try to build your project in the Release configuration and confirm that it is correctly building there, as it does appear (based on your comment) that you have a Release configuration set up.  If that does not work as well, then your problem may be beyond just a missing configuration, which is already a strange problem to have for the Debug configuration.

**Edit:**  If you do not have a propertyGroup for debug at all, then it should not correctly build in debug.  In your case, I would try adding something like this (I made a new c++ project and copied this out of it.  My previous example was from a c# project, so the properties were different, but the idea is the same.)  **I would advise backing up your project before manually making changes to the project file.**  It might be helpful to make a brand new c++ project and compare it's .csproj file to yours.  Besides what I have listed below, there are several more sections for each configuration that should be in your c++ project.

```
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'" Label="Configuration">
    <ConfigurationType>Application</ConfigurationType>
    <UseDebugLibraries>true</UseDebugLibraries>
    <PlatformToolset>v110</PlatformToolset>
    <CharacterSet>MultiByte</CharacterSet>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: The build box was checked, but here's what I got when I opened the file in a text editor:
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'" Label="Configuration">
    <ConfigurationType>Application</ConfigurationType>
    <UseDebugLibraries>false</UseDebugLibraries>
    <PlatformToolset>v110</PlatformToolset>
    <WholeProgramOptimization>true</WholeProgramOptimization>
    <CharacterSet>MultiByte</CharacterSet>
  </PropertyGroup>